# Internationalization(i18n) for Javascript alert messages

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, internationalization, locale

I wish I find a solution for this.**How can internationalization be implemented for Javascript Alert messages?**. I have already implemented i18n from my jsp pages. I am using spring MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using resource bundle you can achieve i18N in java script. see the following Tutorial

[I18n Strings in Javascript](http://rockycode.com/blog/i18n-strings-javascript/)

Comment: I did it :) using plain JavaScript, just passing the strings as parameters from the JSP .